# Replace entry in specific numpy array stored in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I have a dictionary containing a variable number of numpy arrays (all same length), each array is stored in its respective key.

For each index I want to replace the value in one of the arrays by a newly calculated value. (This is a very simplyfied version what I'm actually doing.)

The problem is that when I try this as shown below, the value at the current index of every array in the dictionary is replaced, not just the one I specify.

Sorry if the formatting of the example code is confusing, it's my first question here (Don't quite get how to show the line `example_dict["key1"][idx] = idx+10` properly indented in the next line of the for loop...).

```
>>> import numpy as np 

>>> example_dict = dict.fromkeys(["key1", "key2"], np.array(range(10)))

>>> example_dict["key1"]
```

> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

```
>>> example_dict["key2"]
```

> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

```
>>> for idx in range(10):
    example_dict["key1"][idx] = idx+10



>>> example_dict["key1"]
```

> array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])

```
>>> example_dict["key2"]
```

> array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])

I expected the loop to only access the array in `example_dict["key1"]`, but somehow the same operation is applied to the array stored in  `example_dict["key2"]` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> hex(id(example_dict["key1"]))
'0x26a543ea990'
>>> hex(id(example_dict["key2"]))
'0x26a543ea990'
```

`example_dict["key1"]` and `example_dict["key2"]` are pointing at the same address. To fix this, you can use a dict comprehension.

```
import numpy
keys = ["key1", "key2"]
example_dict = {key: numpy.array(range(10)) for key in keys}
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixes the problem. Although I am wondering why the function made for exactly this specific purpose (`dict.fromkeys()`) would introduce this problem in the first place...